# How can I add an option to ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to extend Rails associations such as has_and_belongs_to_many with a `cache` option:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, cache: true
```

It works fine when I'm directly editing the bundled ActiveRecord gem:

```
module ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder
  class CollectionAssociation < Association #:nodoc:
    [...]    
    def valid_options
      super + [:table_name, :finder_sql, :counter_sql, :before_add,
               :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend,
               :cache]
    end
    [...]
  end
end
```

But I'm not sure about a clean way to either monkeypatch, override or extend this class.

Comment: Are HABTM relationships not automatically cached the first time they are requested?

Comment: there is no "clean" way here :) it might be worth having a look at [identity cache](https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache) it might be doing what you are trying to implement.

Comment: True but ActiveRecord and Identity Cache don't do exactly what I want to do, which I'm doing manually everywhere in my app and trying to extract :)